# Show bounds of a custom drawable on screen

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

In order to analysis a layout from some open sources, how can I show bounds of the custom drawable programmatically on screen.

In my case, a custom view add a custom drawable programmatically inside it.

Comment: @pskink The drawable isn't in xml. In my case, a custom view add a custom drawable programmatically inside it .

Comment: @pskink Could you give me an example?

Comment: @pskink I'm not clear about this, could you explain in more detail. A complete code would be appreciated.